# scheme out of memory racket using cond instead of if

Tags: loops, scheme, racket, infinite, sicp

I'm working on my homework in scheme. I'm asking for help with it.
Basically, we created a faculty procedure and it worked. Then we rewrote the if statement using cond. When the procedure is executed now, Racket runs out of memory. I suppose we get into an infinite loop. But why?

First, here's the code

The first implementation for faculty of n.

```
(define (facult n)
  (define (iter product counter)
    (if (> counter n)
        product
        (iter (* counter product)(+ counter 1))))
  (iter 1 1))
```

Now we replace if by using this custom cond statement.

```
(define (new-if-statement predicate then-clause else-clause)
  (cond(predicate then-clause)
       (else else-clause)))
```

Changing the origininal faculty procedure to:

```
(define (facult n)
  (define (iter product counter)
    (new-if-statement (> counter n)
            product
            (iter (* counter product)(+ counter 1))))
  (iter 1 1))
```

Things I know:
In if you may only use one statement when the "then" statement is executed (same with else). Conditional allows you to use more than one statement after each predicate.

But how does this help me finding a solution for the infinite loop?

Comment: It's not a difference between `cond` and `if`. You'll notice that if you replace the `cond` in the body of the `new-if-stament` function back with `if`, then you get the same infinite loop result. The real relavant difference is that there's a function call in between.

Comment: Hey @AlexKnauth, thank you for your response.
So the problem is that we call "new-function-statement"? But why does this create a problem?

Edit: Your link explained everything. Thank you!

Comment: You have forgotten to thunk the arguments to your if. Without doing so both branches are evaluated.

Comment: `new-if-statement` should be not procedure but syntax transformer. You should change `define` to `define-syntax-rule` in `new-if-statement` definition.

Comment: They are not statements, they are expressions, and they are note executed but evaluated.